# Logstash how to install

Tags: logstash

I want to install and start interact using logstash. Have anyone used this before? How can I enable this to my computer and this needs specific knowledge of a programming language? Is there any tutorial for dummies of video tutorial?

Comment: Do you mean [logstash](http://logstash.net/)?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [tutorials](http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.3/tutorials/getting-started-simple) and [cookbook](http://cookbook.logstash.net/) they have provided?

Comment: Also the [10 minute walkthrough](http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.3/tutorials/10-minute-walkthrough/)

Answer (score 2):

First, You computer must have JAVA Runtime. Logstash is a jar executable file. You no need to install it. You can just download from [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/elkdownloads/) and then execute it.

The [logstash website](http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.3/) has full of tutorials. You can visit it. It's easy to learn. You no need to know any specific programming language. (If you want to write your own plugin, you must know ruby). Logstash provides tons of API to do input,filter and output logs.

You can also take a look at how to write [logstash configuration file](http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.3/configuration).

Enjoy it!