# Collect the log data

Tags: logstash, kibana

I have a file which contains log files and I want to use the logstash and Kibana in order to collect them and see them in the visual option which is offered from Kibana.

My problem is that my logfiles have this format nameoflogfile.logs and it is like a format.

How can I use logstash jar for this? Should I write any kind of script?

Answer (score 1):

You question probably same with your question before([Logstash how to install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997750/logstash-how-to-install)).

Logstash is used to parse logs. But if you want to save your logs, you need to specific the output. 
So, if you want to use Kibana, please choose elasticsearch as your logs output. Please refer to this [page](http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.3/tutorials/getting-started-centralized) for whole architecture. Also, you can visit the last answer i reply to your question.